# Insert query not working with column names,

Tags: sqlite, insert

It's working only for name like:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO newtable(name) VALUES ('"+name1+"');");
```

I want to insert these values:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO newtable(name,father,city,number,anything) Values('" + name1 + "','" + father1 +"','"+city+"','"+number1+"','"+anything1+ "') ;");
```

Answer (score 0):

check this. it worked for me and quite easy.

```
    this.openDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("CategoryName", name);
    values.put("CategoryPosition", pos);
    long row = Db.insert("CategoryListPosition", null, values);
    Db.close();
```

where values contains field names and values that you want to insert. "CategoryListPosition" is table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentValues to insert values

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
   values.put("Name", name); 
   database.insert("student", null, values); 
   database.close();
```